# Conditional Formatted Strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, string-formatting, conditional-formatting

```
def secondCalculator(days, hours, minutes, seconds):
days = int(input("Days: ")) * 3600 * 24
hours = int(input("Hours: ")) * 3600
minutes = int(input("Minutes: ")) * 60
seconds = int(input("Seconds: "))

allSec = days + hours + minutes + seconds

if days == 1:
    print(f"{days} Days,{hours} Hours, {minutes} Minutes, {seconds} Seconds are equal to {allSec} seconds.")

#### same use of if, for hours, minutes and seconds.
```

If user enters
secondCalculator(0,1,2,5)
Output should be:
0 Day, 1 Hour, 2 Minutes, 5 Seconds is equal to 3725 seconds.

When user enters 1 day, it should be printing "day" not "days", same goes for hour, minutes, second.
The things is making it with an if is doable yes but i thought maybe there are easier ways to do it.

How can i make it put the "s" suffix depending on the entered number by the user.
Can we implement conditional string formatting for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this possibly? Might make sense to wrap it in a function:

```
>>> days = 1
>>> f"day{('s', '')[days==1]}"
'day'
>>> days = 2
>>> f"day{('s', '')[days==1]}"
'days'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if days > 1:
    suffix_day = 'days'
elif days == 0:
    suffix_day = 'days'
else:
    suffix_day = 'day'
```

then use:

```
print(f'{days} {suffix_day})
```

Answer (score 1):

Define:

```
def s(val):
        if val > 1:
            return "s"
        return ""
```

And use it as:

```
print(f"{days} Day{s(days)}
```